# надо чтобы бот выдавал username пользователя по нажатию инлайн кнопки

Tags: python, aiogram

Такая проблема, при нажатии кнопки бот выдает свой username, а надо чтобы выдавал username пользователя

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button99')
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery , ):
        name111 = callback_query.message.from_user.get_mention(as_html=True)
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id , 'Держи❤️' )
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.message.chat.id, rpr)
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.message.chat.id, name111,parse_mode='html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так надо

```
username = callback_query.from_user.username
```

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли, если я сменю на user.id он будет выдавать user.id бота, а мне надо чтобы он отправил username пользователя который нажал на кнопку

Comment: @P1nkSunset мой косяк, пофиксил

Comment: Он теперь он выдаёт свой username, а мне надо того кто нажал на кнопку

Comment: @P1nkSunset бред, он не может выдать юзернейм бота физически, ибо это данные самого колбека а не месседжа

Comment: Извиняюсь, просто нк проверил код и нагнал, все работает спасибо ❤️